# SQL Performance wise which one is better Distinct or group by

Tags: sql, sql-server

I know both of these have different functionalities
in some cases these two meet

As I'm new to SQL server, I'm bit confused to choose one
especially in the below query performance-wise

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.PublicImageId, 
        COUNT(u.PublicImageUpvoteId) OVER(PARTITION BY PublicImageId) AS "Total" 
FROM [PublicImageUpvote] u
```

or

```
SELECT u.PublicImageId, 
      COUNT(u.PublicImageUpvoteId) AS "Total" 
FROM [PublicImageUpvote] u 
GROUP BY u.PublicImageId
```

performance wise which one is better or there will a really ignorable performance difference
especially in queries like these?

Comment: This is a great [article](https://sqlperformance.com/2017/01/t-sql-queries/surprises-assumptions-group-by-distinct) on the subject by Aaron Bertrand.

Comment: Group By is definitely better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you mean

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.PublicImageId,
                COUNT(u.PublicImageUpvoteId)
                  OVER(PARTITION BY PublicImageId) AS "Total"
FROM   [PublicImageUpvote] u
```

vs

```
SELECT u.PublicImageId,
       COUNT(u.PublicImageUpvoteId) AS "Total"
FROM   [PublicImageUpvote] u
GROUP  BY u.PublicImageId
```

Because otherwise they don't do the same thing.

`GROUP BY` will definitely be better (at least in current versions of the product - SQL is declarative and it is possible future versions might recognise the equivalence and optimise them the same).

The execution plan needs to just do the grouping, calculate the aggregate for the group and return the result. It might consider stream or hash aggregate.

The windowed aggregate plan needs to do the grouping, aggregate it, replay a spool with all the rows in the group (which either shows up as a separate common sub expression spool or part of the window aggregate operator) and add the aggregate to them as a new column, then do extra work to remove all the duplicates in the group to just return one row per group. This will always use a stream aggregate type approach too (requiring data to arrive sorted by `PublicImageId`) so even the initial aggregation step may be less efficient in cases where hash aggregate would be preferred.

Comment: yeah, I forgot to add partition by. wow, thanks for the detailed explanation :)